# More efficient way to use args in function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I need to define a function in PHP that contains multiple arguments (as shown below):

```
function the_function($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, $arg6, $arg7, ...)
```

but I believe there is a more efficient and clean method of doing this. Can anyone help me? I thought of using an array, something like that. obs: sorry for the noob question! :b

Edit: i'll use something like

```
function foo(
    'number of topics', 'topics per page', 'topics per line'
     , 'type of topic', 'number of excerpt words'
);
```

Comment: Don't predaclare them. Just use `func_get_args()`, or wait for PHP 5.6

Comment: What is the function supposed to do with all those arguments? Are they of the same type?

Comment: Ah 5.6. I hope they release in February :) - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking

Comment: I'll use something like `function foo('number of topics', 'topics per page', 'topics per line', 'type of topic', 'number of excerpt words')`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can go three ways with this:

1. If **all** arguments are semantically the same, use `func_get_args()` within your function to iterate over the given arguments. A single array argument is a respected alternative.
2. If **most** arguments are semantically the same, group them together as a single array argument. Treat the other arguments separately.
3. In all other cases, group related arguments together into a separate object.

They're not entirely mutually exclusive btw.

Answer (score 1):

An array is the standard approach to avoiding a ton of arguments (if a function does truly need that many). Just consider whether or not the type of things in the array are numerical in nature or if naming them makes sense. You may want to pass in an associate array rather than numerical. Of course, be absolutely sure that the function really needs those arguments and can't be broken down further.

Here's just a random example where an associative array **might** make sense.

```
$phone = [
  'home' => '555-5551',
  'cell' => '555-5552',
  'work' => '555-5553'
];
function updateUserInfo($userId, $age, array $phone) {

}
```

rather than:

```
function updateUserInfo($userId, $age, $homePhone, $cellPhone, $workPhone) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking to declaring your arguments explicitly.  It makes for easier testing and less ambiguity.    Also, you can enforce some type checking on objects and arrays.

```
 function foo( User $user, array $user_friend_ids);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm more of a javascript developer, but in js it's very common to pass objects as arguments (associate array in php) to avoid clutter. I think if the context is right, it shouldn't affect testing and may help readability.

Comment: Yes, I see a lot of JS coders do this in PHP but would caution against the practice.  It will be readable, 'clean' and understandable to you maybe, but not necessarily to the next person.  Also, tools such as IDE's to check code  cannot inspect into a generic array argument to see if the values are correctly being passed in or all of the needed arguments are present.

Comment: I agree in those contexts. Same goes for javascript. A numerical arrays makes a ton of sense in a lot of situations (such as your example), but an assoc. array does once in a while - I'll update my answer.